Why is the solution not continuous?
In the ODE $x'(t) = x^2(t)$ we find the general solution is $x(t) = \frac{-1}{x-c}$ for some constant $c$. However to find a specific solution we need the initial value $x(t_0)=x_0$ and we must also find the interval of validity of this ODE. It's clear that the interval cannot contain $x=c$. When defining the interval, the textbook I am using separates the real line into two intervals where the function could be defined, depending on the sign of $x_0$. My question is, why can't we just state that the solution works everywhere in $R$ except $x=c$? The textbook says it wouldn't be continous, but the function is continous if $c$ is not in the domain, so why do we need to separate the interval?

One shall view the interval of the solution is so called "Generated" by the ODE. Sometimes, the behaviour of the solution of IVP may change (some solution implicitly defined such as $y^2=x$, then it depends on whether the initial condition is positive or negative, and both corresponding to different domains).

You have freedom to extend your solution to the other interval, but it will not result in a unique solution overall (on both disconnected intervals together). See "existence and uniqueness theorems." Normally, such theorems have to do with continuous solutions existing on some open interval (as opposed to broken over several such disconnected intervals).

It is a uniqueness issue. Take $x_0=1$, then we have $x(t) = \frac{1}{1-t}$ for $t\in(-\infty,1)$. Additionally, $\frac{1}{1-t}$ is a solution to the ODE for $(1,\infty)$, as you say. However, notice that
$$
y(t) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{1-t}, & t<1 \\ \frac{1}{c-t}, & t>1
\end{cases}
$$
satisfies the initial condition and is also a continuous solution to the ODE on $t\in\mathbb{R}\setminus\{1\}$ for any $c<1$. For this reason, we typically only deal with existence and uniqueness in some maximal interval containing the initial condition. Indeed, you may find that your textbook's definition of "interval of validity" specifies that it is an interval in which the solution exist and is unique, which is the critical issue here.

By definition, the solution of an ODE is continuous (continuously differentiable) on its domain. The domain is always an open interval.
If you get an expression for the solution that has singularities as in the current case, its domain is split into a union of open intervals. You need to select the one that contains the initial point.
There are situation where a generalized or extended solution concept is appropriate. These are then also described as such. However, even generalized solutions are at least continuous on their domain.
It should be remarked that discontinuous solutions or approximations occur in the context of differential equations, for instance in finite volume methods (FVM). But even there the aim is to stay close to (piecewise) continuous functions.

But the solution to this ODE would still be continous on the interval $(-\infty,\infty)/c$ would it not? The only discontinuity is at the point $x=c$. The only problem as I understand would be uniqueness, not existence or continuity

At $x=c$ the solution leaves the domain towards infinity. ODE solutions are descriptions of some dynamic, some physical situation. Nature does not allow infinite jumps. Thus the solution ends there. That the solution be continuous on an open interval ensures the continuity of the solution as dynamical process. As said, generalizations are possible, but then they are not simply named "solution of an ODE".

You are right that the solution is continuous on the line minus the singularity point. The problem is in what we want to refer to as the solution. This problem is tricking us into believing there is some canonical solution because we have a formula for it, but existence and uniqueness theory makes no such distinction. There is no unique way to extend the solution of an IVP past a singularity. The only reason we think we can for this problem is because the formula that defines our solution happens to be defined somewhere else as well.
